# Redirect after login with C# to HTML page. But one should not open that HTML just by copying that URL

Tags: c#, asp.net, authentication, response.redirect

I am new to ASP.Net and C#.
I want to perform login with C# and then want to redirect to HTML file.
This HTML is SuperGIS server start page.

I am using somthing like this:

```
    <%@ Page Language="C#" Debug="true" %>

    <!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"  "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <script runat="server">

    protected void btnlogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
    if(some code to check username and password exist in DB)
        Response.Redirect("http://localhost/AddMarker/MapEditor.htm");
        else
         Response.Redirect("http://localhost/AddMarker/Login.aspx");

    }

    </script>


<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title>Login Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">

    <div>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 
        Sign In<br />
        <br />
<asp:Label ID="lblUsername" runat="server" Text="Username"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtUsername" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp; 

        <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="RequiredFieldValidator1" runat="server" ControlToValidate = "txtUsername"
            ErrorMessage="This Feild is Mendetory"></asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
<br />
<br />
<asp:Label ID="lblPassword" runat="server" Text="Password"></asp:Label>
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:TextBox ID="txtPassword" runat="server" TextMode="Password"></asp:TextBox>
<br />
<br />
&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
<asp:Button ID="btnlogin" runat="server" Text="Login" onclick="btnlogin_Click" 
Width="47px" />
&nbsp;
<br />

&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
</div>

    </form>
    <a href="forgetpass.aspx">Forgt Password</a><br>
    <a href="Create.aspx">New User</a>
</body>
</html>
```

This code will redirect to desired destination. But at that time url will be
   -->"http://localhost/AddMarker/MapEditor.htm"

which is due to code:    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/AddMarker/MapEditor.htm");

Thus any one can copy this URL and access this services without authentication.

So can I create some dynamic URL which one cant use without giving correct ID and password.

Please help me.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: [Forms authentication](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xdt4thhy(v=vs.100).aspx) is probably what you should be looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You can use session state to store if a user is authenticated.

```
if(some code to check username and password exist in DB) 
{
    HttpContext.Current.Session("UserIsAuthenticated") = True
    Response.Redirect("http://localhost/AddMarker/MapEditor.htm"); 
}
```

You can set your session time in `web.config` so that you only stay authenticated for a certain amount of time. Then in the load event of the pages where you need to be authenticated use this:

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Session("UserIsAuthenticated") == null)
   //User needs to login
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
else if(!HttpContext.Current.Session("UserIsAuthenticated"))
   //User needs to login
   Response.Redirect("Login.aspx")
```

You could also do this with cookies, but I would recomend not doing this where possible due to the new leigislations with cookies.

Comment: This way it didn't work for me. As it was giving error for line"HttpContext.Current.Session("UserIsAuthenticated")" so I have pasted my mapeditot.html in defult.aspx file. Now its working fine.

Comment: @so_ what error? If this has worked would you accept the answer to prevent people from attempting to answer your question.

Comment: sorry LukeHennerley It didnt work.. I was getting syntax error for "HttpContext.Current.Session("UserIsAuthenticated")". So I was not bale to run and test.

Comment: @so_ sorry just notice that the `is nothing` was VB.Net code... Would've though someone else may have picked that up and flagged it. Change that to `== null` as per my edit and it should work.

Answer (score 0):

this can be done using http handlers, read more about it here:

1. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398986(v=vs.100).aspx
2. http://codebetter.com/karlseguin/2006/05/25/httphandlers-%E2%80%93-learn-them-use-them/
3. http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/advanced/httphandler-aspnet2-csharp.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way would be using ASP .Net in your MapEditor.htm to check the access. When the user is authenticated you store in the Session your flag. Then, you check this flag always in your MapEditor.**aspx**

Answer (score 0):

You should place your logged in state check in Global.asax.  Use one of the events like Application_BeginRequest to see if the user is logged in and redirect if not.  You will need to make sure that the page the user is trying to pull up is not the login page though otherwise it wont work.

**Update**: Here is some code that I used in a masterpage which works well.  If you are not using masterpages then the Global.asax will work if you place this in the right spots.

Note that this code is geared towards checking if the user is in a specific domain group since the site is using Windows Authentication.  You can swap out whatever method you need to validate the user.  Also the AccessException bool is set to true in my NoAccess page so that it actually gets displayed. Finally, the check is cached so we dont have to keep checking it.

```
public bool AccessException;

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    UpdateNavigation();

    if (!HasAccess() && !AccessException)
    {
        Response.Redirect("~/NoAccess.aspx", true);
    }
}

/// <summary>
/// Check domain group membership to make sure the user is allowed to use the web site; redirect if not.
/// </summary>
/// <returns>True if the user has access to the site</returns>
private bool HasAccess()
{
    if (Page.Cache["hasAccess"] == null)
    {
        List<string> userDomainGroups = Common.GetUserDomainGroups(Request.LogonUserIdentity);
        string permittedGroups = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AllowedGroups"];

        Page.Cache["hasAccess"] = userDomainGroups.Where(permittedGroups.Contains).Count() != 0; ;
    }

    return (bool)Page.Cache["hasAccess"];
}
```